# "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" with Babel, Jest, and webpack

Tags: webpack, jestjs, babeljs

I have a problem with configurations of Babel 7, Webpack 4 and Jest.
While I'm running tests I'm getting following error:

**SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module**

**package.json**

```
 "@babel/core": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/highlight": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "^0.4.2",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.5",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-serializer-vue": "^2.0.2",
    "jest-transform-stub": "^2.0.0",
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
  entry: {
      app: ["./src/index.js"]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('../', 'static/js/'), 
    filename: "[name].js",
    publicPath: '/static/js/', 
    chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js' 
  },
```

**.babelrc** - I assumed that the problem is with module: false but if I dont include that, webpack doesnt chunk my files.

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {"modules": false}, "jest" ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import" 
  ],
    "env": {  
      "test": {
        "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"],
      }
    }
}
```

When I removed module: false tests were running, are there any chances to dont include module: false into tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Babel Options documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#env):

> Note: env[envKey] options will be merged on top of the options specified in the root object.

So you can apply `modules: "auto"` during testing by redeclaring the plugin in the `env.test` object:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": false
      },
      "jest"
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          {
            "modules": "auto"
          },
          "jest"
        ]
      ],
      "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`import` statements are only permitted in ES modules. Your tests are running in Node which uses commonjs modules.

Try adding `"type": "module"` to your `package.json` file

Also check the version of Node you are running, you can find more on this in the node docs https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_ecmascript_modules

Comment: I've tried, unfortunately doesnt work.. module:false in the babelrc isnot excluding the type: module from package.json ?

Answer (score 0):

Since `jest@25.4.0`, it is not needed to transpile code to support esm in tests anymore as it supports it natively. You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61653104/3514603), how to achieve that as it is not documented yet.