# Node v13 / Jest / ES6 — native support for modules without babel or esm

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, jestjs

Is it possible to test ES6 Modules with Jest without `esm` or `babel`? Since `node v13` supports es6 natively have tried:

```
//package.json
{
  …
  "type": "module"
  …
}



//__tests__/a.js
import Foo from '../src/Foo.js';


$ npx jest

Jest encountered an unexpected token
…
Details:

/home/node/xxx/__tests__/a.js:1
import Foo from '../src/Foo.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

When babel is added a transpiler, it works, but can es6 modules be used natively as well?

Comment: Is Foo being default export from '../src/Foo.js' ?

Comment: yes, that is the case.

Comment: According to issue [#9430](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9430), (and other issues that are either _referenced_ or _mentioned_ in this issue), it seems that babel or esm are still necessary.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes, it is possible from `jest@25.4.0`. From this version, there is a native support of esm, so you will not have to transpile your code with babel anymore.

It is not documented yet, but according to [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9430) you have to do 3 easy steps to achieve that (*At the time of writing this answer*):

- Make sure you don't transform away `import` statements by setting `transform: {}` in your jest config file
- Run `node@^12.16.0 || >=13.2.0` with `--experimental-vm-modules` flag
- Run your test with `jest-environment-node` or `jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen`.

So your jest config file should contain at least this:

```
export default {
    testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-node',
    transform: {}
    ...
};
```

And to set `--experimental-vm-modules` flag, you will have to run Jest from `package.json` as follows (*I hope this will change in the future*):

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
}
```

I hope, this answer was helpful to you.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't really work very well. The `jest` name isn't available within the test module. I'm sure there are other problems too as per the linked issue. Sadly it looks like Babel is the way to go for now.

Comment: Didn't work for me using node 14 and jest 26. If I remove `transform` I get the following error `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: I was struggling with the issue described by @sdt, but I finally discovered that the `jest` object "can also be imported explicitly via `import {jest} from '@jest/globals'`" https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object

Comment: Do not forget to set "type": "module" in package.json

Comment: The changes to the jest config weren't necessary for me. Just specifying `"type": "module"` in the package.json and running node with `--experimental-vm-modules` was enough (Jest 26.6.3 and node v14.15.4).

Also a little cleaner way to specify the test command: `"test": "NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules jest"`

Comment: FYI, using ESM in `testEnvironment` was only added in 27.0.0: https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/11232

Comment: Weather not the config change is needed will depend on your setup. import() is understood by both commonJS and ESM and will load either of these. This is needed for mixed settings. In pure esm settings  transform: {} insures jest doesn't use babel and mess with things.

Comment: I had to add `{ test: /\.m?js/, resolve: {fullySpecified: false}},` in webpack.config.cjs module -> rules to avoid changing all my imports

Comment: I got it to work with scripts: {"test": "node --experimental-vm-modules $(yarn bin jest)"} in package.json

Comment: An update in the answer as of early 2023?

Answer (score 6):

Note that this is is still experimental, but we *have* documented how to test this, so there's hopefully less confusion.

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules

The steps in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61653104/1850276 are correct

Answer (score 4):

I followed the tips provided in the accepted answer, but I added the property `"type": "module"` in my `package.json` in order to jest works properly. This is what I done:

In `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^26.1.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen": "^1.0.3",
    "jest-environment-node": "^26.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "jest": {
    "transform": {},
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen"
  }
```

Comment: The changes to the jest configuration weren't necessary for me as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60372790/node-v13-jest-es6-native-support-for-modules-without-babel-or-esm#comment116654281_61653104)

Answer (score 3):

To run jest from "jest" extension in VSCode with "--experimental-vm-modules" flags, put this config in your global or workspaces settings.json:

```
"jest.nodeEnv": {

    "NODE_OPTIONS": "--experimental-vm-modules"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Radovan Kuka's answer, here's how to run Jest with ES modules, using `npx`:

```
"test:monitoring": "npx --node-arg=--experimental-vm-modules jest -f monitoring.test.js --detectOpenHandles",
```

The benefit is that one doesn't need to provide the absolute `node_modules` path.

Comment: With 27.0.0-next.8, I took the `npx` out of the commands and everything's working fine.

Comment: on npx 8.3.1 it write "npx: the --node-arg argument has been removed." and test continue to fail

Comment: @perymimon That clearly puts my comments to rest. But so does the soon release of Jest 28 which has native ESM support.

Answer (score 1):

Without Babel, here's a complete, minimal example that works on recent Jest versions. Run with `npm test`.

```bash
$ tree -I node_modules
.
├── package.json
├── src
│   └── foo.js
└── __tests__
    └── foo.spec.js
```

`package.json`:

```js
{
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^29.3.1"
  }
}
```

`src/foo.js`:

```js
export const bar = () => 42;
```

`__tests__/foo.spec.js`:

```js
import {bar} from "../src/foo";

describe("foo.bar()", () => {
  it("should return 42", () => {
    expect(bar()).toBe(42);
  });
});
```

The secret sauce is in the `package.json`: `"type": "module"` and `NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules jest`.

If you want to add a mock, it's a bit complicated. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71044616/6243352).