# How to enable es6 import modules in Jest in a ESM used back-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, jestjs, babeljs

I'm using a NodeJs backend with ESM package enabled mode to use es6+ import modules system when I'm trying to access a file in my test, even if I use require in my test file because target file uses import/export, it throws this error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I know, I can use babel to solve Jest problem, but due to my main project files (which are using ESM), is there any solution to config Jest with ESM?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node v13 / Jest / ES6 — native support for modules without babel or esm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60372790/node-v13-jest-es6-native-support-for-modules-without-babel-or-esm)

Answer (score 2):

I have a good news to you. Jest supports esm natively from version `25.4.0`. It is not documented yet, but I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61653104/3514603), how to achieve that.

I hope, it will help to you.

Comment: Nice, I didn't kow that!
But instead of answering with a link to another question, [mark it as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: Thank you, but I haven't enough reputation to do that :/