# Error with Jest when trying to use `import`

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am using Jest to run tests on my JS code.
But currently, I am having an error:
`Cannot use import statement outside a module`
How can i fix this ?
I looked here but it does not what i am looking for: [How to resolve "Cannot use import statement outside a module" in jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58613492/how-to-resolve-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-in-jest)

This is my module:

```
class Path {
  // code in here
}

export default Path;
```

This is the test file that exported from it:

```
import Path from "./Path";
// test() ...
```

This is my folder structure:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried import { Path } from "./Path";

Comment: There's a similar thread that explains the issue you are experiencing quite well. Check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60372790/node-v13-jest-es6-native-support-for-modules-without-babel-or-esm/61653104#61653104